# Why my setters can't be activated although I've made pointers for parameters?

Tags: c++, oop

Hi everyone I'm a newbie to programming and self-taught C++ by a website.
I'm writing a program to calculate the distance between the beginning and the end point. Here's my code

File Point.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#pragma once

using namespace std;

class Point {
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Point() {
        
    }
    Point(int x, int y) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }
    void setX(int x) {
        this->x = x;
    }
    int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    void setY(int y) {
        this->y = y;
    }
    int getY() {
        return y;
    }
};
```

File Line.cpp :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include "Point.cpp"

class Line {
private:
    Point begin;
    Point end;
public:
    Line(Point begin, Point end) {
        this->begin = begin;
        this->end = end;
    }
    Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        x1 = begin.getX();
        y1 = begin.getY();
        x2 = end.getX();
        y2 = end.getY();
    }
    void setBegin(Point begin) {
        begin.setX(int x1);
        begin.setY(int y1);
    }
    Point getBegin() {
        return begin;
    }
    void setEnd(Point end) {
        end.setX(int x2);
        end.setY(int y2);
    }
    Point getEnd() {
        return end;
    }
    double getLength() {
        return sqrt( (begin.getX() - end.getY())*(begin.getX() - end.getY()) + (begin.getX() - end.getY())*(begin.getX() - end.getY()) );
    }
    
};
```

In file Line.cpp, the setEnd and setBegin can't run and the error said "type name is not allowed" for the parameters of setters although I've made pointers for them.

Hope anyone can have a good explanation and fix my code.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't use websites to learn C++, use [good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). [Why is `using namespace std;` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: It looks like you want `this->begin.setX(begin.x)`. Naming your parameters the same as the members creates all sorts of problems and confusion. Name the parameters something different and you can drop all the `this->` stuff.

Comment: Take a closer look at lines like `begin.setX(int x1);` or `end.setX(int x2);`

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Or simply `this->begin = begin;`

Comment: @Evg Can you recommend me any good books?

Comment: Also note that using `.cpp` file for `#include` is a bad havit that may lead to muitiple-definition error. In this case it looks like just the name is wrong and they should named as `.h` or `.hpp`.

Comment: @Ruzihm those are where my error comes and I'm asking abt that :)))

Comment: @NgôSơn Evg gave two links. This first is to Stack Overflow's volunteer-curated list of well-regarded C++ programming texts.

Comment: `Point() {}` -- You failed to initialize the members of `Point` in the default constructor.  Thus trying to get the distance will lead to all sorts of weird results.

Comment: `Line`'s second constructor doesn't make any sense. What do you expect it to accomplish?

Comment: @NgôSơn In `setBegin` what is the `int x1` meant to do? what happens to `begin` when that function ends?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I want to give x1, y1 as coordinates of begin point and x2,y2 the coordinates of another point

Comment: @NgôSơn -- `double length = Line(Point(), Point()).getLength();` -- what do you think `length` will be equal to?  No one knows since `Point` has a default constructor that doesn't initialize the `x` or `y` members.  The `length` could be `0`, `1.0`, `432.324382,` you don't know.

Comment: But why do you "give x1, y1 as coordinates of begin point and x2,y2 the coordinates of another point" in a constructor of a completely unrelated object? This is a constructor for the object that ***contains these points*** and ***receives x1, y1, x2, and y2 as parameters***. As Mr. Spock would say: "this is highly illogical".

Comment: "Setters" really get my goat.  To me they are the quintessential antipattern, making your code tightly-coupled peek-poke style, puncturing any encapsulation you have provided.  "Getters" are OK.  Get into the habit of thinking of "operations to perform on an object" instead of poking attributes like an assembly programmer :)

Comment: With what you have here, I would be writing "xDiff" and "yDiff" methods in Point, so you can get the x,y deltas between two points.  Then your getLength uses them and does the Pythagoras to calculate the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tenphase has already mentioned that you should not put `int` in the line:

```
begin.setX(int x1)
           ^^^
```

However, there seems to have a lot more problem with your code here. Your `Point` class seems to work fine, however you seems to have a lot of problems with your `Line` class.

---

For instance, in your `setBegin` function, even after removing the `int`s in there:

```
void setBegin(Point begin) {
    begin.setX(x1);
    begin.setY(y1);
}
```

- First, you don't actually have `x1` or `y1`. So attempting to call `x1` would fail right away.

---

- Second, let's say you do have `x1` and `y1` as the x and y for your beginning point, and imagining you already have a `Line line` defined, and you will be calling `setBegin` like:

```
Point p1(0, 5);
line.setBegin(p1);
```

What this does is not actually setting the beginning point of your `line` to `(0,5)`. Instead, you are first creating a copy of `p1` and pass that to the `setBegin` function. Then you perform `setX` and `setY` on that copied `p1`, and set it to the location of your `line`'s `x1` and `y1`.

However, this doesn't actually affect anything. Your `line` remains unchanged, and the `p1` that was modified was actually a copy of your original `p1`, which will be deleted right after the function.

What you actually want might be:

```
void setBegin(Point new_point) {
    begin.setX(new_point.getX());
    begin.setY(new_point.getY());
}
```

Here I changed the parameter `begin` to `new_point`, so it's easier to differentiate it with `this->begin`. Then it sets x of `begin` to x of `new_point`, and sets y of `begin` to y of `new_point`.

---

Alternatively, you can also use:

```
void setBegin(Point new_point) {
    begin = new_point;
}
```

Now you just set `begin` as the same as `new_point`.

The exact same problem happens to your `setEnd`

---

While a little bit different, but your `Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)` also suffers similar problems.

```
x1 = begin.getX();
```

It first creates a copy of `x1`, then modify the value of `x1` to the x of `begin`. Instead, you are likely looking for:

```
begin.setX(x1);
```

Comment: Ok I understand. Thank you for clarification and I think need to find books about algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Like *@Ruzihm* perfectly noticed, a call to a function **shall not** specify the type of the variable passed to the function...

In your code:

```
void setBegin(Point begin) {
    begin.setX(int x1);
    begin.setY(int y1);
}
```

Remove the **int** where you call the functions, and it should already go a little better... *:P*

> **Note**
> After a second reading, I would rather say that **it should at least compile** *maybe*...
> But it seems that there are other problems in your code...

> **Most Obvious One**
> The constructor `Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)` is assigning the values of the coordinate stored by the members `begin` and `end` to the parameters of the constructor itself...
>
> This is clearly something that will **never** do what you expect...
> You are changing the values of the argument of the constructor. It is allowed and causes no errors, but it will have absolutely not side effect *(it won't change the state of the constructed object)*...
>
> *(keep trying – things cannot be learned without doing mistakes)*

Comment: Do not use asterisks `*` inside the code, as it could be confused with pointers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you're perfectly right, I didn't think about it, thanks. I wanted to emphasis somehow where the error was...